# Powershell and jenkins foreach loops

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a function in Powershell and want to run this on many servers.

It's running from Jenkins via a Powershell step, the input param `$env:servers` is configured as a "Muli-line String".

Simple example:

```
function test {
    param(    
        [string]$servername
    )
    #do somthing 
}


$servers = $env:servers 
foreach ($s in $servers) {
    test -servername $s
}
```

But when I build it with parametrs, the `foreach` does not work - it treats `$servers` like a single string. What's wrong?

Comment: Print out the $env:servers to see the content of that `Write-Host $env:servers` Can yo please say if there is content.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with the code. Your $env:servers is a empty variable

Comment: Maybe `$servers = $env:servers -split ';'`? Apply correct delimiter instead of `;`  semicolon.

Comment: i try -split, and .split(''), that dont work...                                                   
jnkns1 (windows) in workspace d:\Jenkins\workspace\test\TestJOb
[TestJOb] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins282267647354535141.ps1'"
Cannot convert value "\\serv1serv2\root\default:StdRegProv" to type "System.Management.ManagementClass". Error: "The RPC server is unavailable. (
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your input param (`$env:servers`) is a multi-line string, `$servers` will also be a single multi-line string.

To use this with `foreach` it needs to be an array of strings, you will need to split `$env:servers` so `$servers` becomes an array of strings with each line an item. This is very simple to do using `Split()` ([blog on this subject](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/)):

```
$servers = ($env:servers).Split([Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This will split on `NewLine` and deal with any blank lines by removing an empty entries from the final output.

---

Example code to show this behaviour for future reference to others:

```
$input_servers = @"
server1
server2
server3
"@

$servers = $input_servers.Split([Environment]::NewLine, [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Write-Output "Server Name: $server"
}
```